# Trac/Agilo got broken after OS upgrade

Tags: linux, svn, trac, genshi

I did an os upgrade from `debian etch` to `squeeze` and after that my `trac`/`agilo` died, the problem is that when committing code to `subversion` it gets trough, but at the same time `trac`/`agilo` gives this error:

```
2012-11-26 16:44:37,766 Trac[loader] ERROR: Skipping "agilo.utils.web_ui = agilo.utils.web_ui": (version conflict "VersionConflict: (Genshi 0.6 (/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.5), Requirement.parse('genshi>=0.5.1,<0.6dev'))")
```

I cannot see my changes in `trac`/`agilo`, thou they are in the subversion.

I managed to downgrade `genshi` to 0.5.1, but then the committing does not work anymore.

Also if symlinking `/usr/bin/python` (using 2.5) to `python2.6` then the `trac`/`agilo` dies completely.

```
trac                                     0.11.7-4
subversion                               1.6.12dfsg-6
python-genshi                            0.6-1
python2.5                                2.5.5-11
python2.6                                2.6.6-8+b1
```

--bp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like Agilo requires Genshi 0.5, but your system has version 0.6 installed.

I don't recommend downgrading Genshi to resolve this, as doing that will probably break Trac.  Genshi is a dependency of Trac, and Genshi v0.6 was probably installed due to Trac being upgraded to a version that requires v0.6.

There are two ways to resolve this.  First, make sure that you are running the latest version of the Agilo plugin.  Your OS upgrade probably also included a Trac upgrade as well.  Certain versions of Trac require certain versions of the Agilo plugin (see the Agilo website for details).  What versions of Trac/Genshi were you running before the OS upgrade?

If you can't resolve this by updating the Agilo plugin, you can always re-install your old versions of Trac and Genshi.  Remove Trac/Genshi using your package manager, and then install them manually from source.  By doing this, you can ensure that you are installing the exact version that your system was using before the OS upgrade.  This might be a bit more hassle since you won't be able to update Trac via the normal system update mechanism, but it should at least get you up and running.

Comment: It seems that updating the agilo plugin did the trick, no more errors in trac log, found even excellent instructions for it at  https://agilo.agilofortrac.com/wiki/agilo/dev/users/UpgradeGuide   Thank You                                                                                                             --bp